# Delete duplicate values in php array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have an array that named `$keys`.
The `$keys` values are:

```
$keys[0] = "1/7/95"
$keys[1] = "1/7/95"
$keys[2] = "1/7/95"
$keys[3] = "1/7/95"
$keys[4] = "22/7/95"
$keys[5] = "22/7/95"
$keys[6] = "22/7/95"
$keys[7] = "11/7/95"
$keys[8] = "11/7/95"
$keys[9] = "11/7/95"
$keys[10] = "11/7/95"
$keys[11] = "main page"
```

I need to delete duplicated values in this array. But when I used the `array_unique()` function the result was:

```
"1/7/95"
```

Why?

This is my code, I use this code to make telegram bot keyboard:

```
$list_product = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `product` = '".$item_group['id']."' AND `status`='0' ");
while($item_type = mysql_fetch_array($list_product))
{
    $keys[$j] = array($item_type['detail']);
    $j++;
}

$keys[$j] = array('','main page'."\xF0\x9F\x94\x99");
$keys= array_unique($keys,SORT_NUMERIC);
$replyMarkup = array(
    'keyboard' => $keys
);

$list_setting = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `setting` ");
$item_setting = mysql_fetch_array($list_setting);

$encodedMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup);
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$item_setting['token'].'/sendMessage';

$ch = curl_init( );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "text=".$text_reply."&chat_id=".$user_id."&reply_markup=" .$encodedMarkup);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500 );
$agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$check = curl_exec( $ch );

echo('OK!');
```

But in my bot keyboard I just recieve `"1/7/95"`.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you've tried. Using `$arr = array_unique($arr);`  will give you the output: `Array
(
    [0] => 1/7/95
    [4] => 22/7/95
    [7] => 11/7/95
    [11] => main page
)`

Comment: Try with array_values(array_unique($array_name)).

Comment: array_unique() work fine : https://eval.in/703489

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$keys = array();
$keys[0] = "1/7/95";
$keys[1] = "1/7/95";
$keys[2] = "1/7/95";
$keys[3] = "1/7/95";
$keys[4] = "22/7/95";
$keys[5] = "22/7/95";
$keys[6] = "22/7/95";
$keys[7] = "11/7/95";
$keys[8] = "11/7/95";
$keys[9] = "11/7/95";
$keys[10] = "11/7/95";
$keys[11] = "main page";
$keys = array_unique($keys);
print_r($keys);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_unique()` returns an array with all the unique values, so I'm assuming you're just using/printing the first value?

Doing

```
print_r(array_unique($keys);
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1/7/95
    [4] => 22/7/95
    [7] => 11/7/95
    [11] => main page
)
```

See working example: https://3v4l.org/fOm2s

[The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) states

> Takes an input array and returns a **new array** without duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to share code sample you are using. Any way here is a sample code to explain.

```
<?php    
$keys    = array();
$keys[0] = "1/7/95";
$keys[1] = "1/7/95";
$keys[2] = "1/7/95";
$keys[3] = "1/7/95";
$keys[4] = "22/7/95";
$keys[5] = "22/7/95";
$keys[6] = "22/7/95";
$keys[7] = "11/7/95";
$keys[8] = "11/7/95";
$keys[9] = "11/7/95";
$keys[10] = "11/7/95";
$keys[11] = "main page";

$uniq_keys    = array_unique($keys);
$uniq = array_keys(array_flip($keys));

var_dump($uniq_keys);
/*
array (size=4)
  0 => string '1/7/95' (length=6)
  4 => string '22/7/95' (length=7)
  7 => string '11/7/95' (length=7)
  11 => string 'main page' (length=9)
*/
var_dump($uniq);
/*
array (size=4)
  0 => string '1/7/95' (length=6)
  1 => string '22/7/95' (length=7)
  2 => string '11/7/95' (length=7)
  3 => string 'main page' (length=9)
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For that is you want to only unique value from the table you can add group by in your query. Like:-

```
"SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `product` = '".$item_group['id']."' AND `status`='0'  GROUP BY DATE";
```